# Redirect alias but not IP

Tags: debian, virtualhost, redirect

I have a virtual private server under debian 7 .

On this server I have a website accessible at let's say https://www.monsiteweb.fr

My IP adress is let's say **212.227.100.200** and I can acess to **phpMyAdmin** through *212.227.100.200/phpmyadmin*

I want to redirect people who write monsiteweb.fr *.monsiteweb.fr to https://www.monsiteweb.fr.

The problem is that when I do this redirection, I can no any more access to 212.227.100.200/phpmyadmin which is automatically rewritten to *htps://www.monsiteweb.fr/phpmyadmin* (I write htps instead of https because I can't add more than 2 links on the post)

How can I do so that monsiteweb.fr *.monsiteweb.fr are redirected to *htps://www.monsiteweb.fr* but **212.227.100.200** is not redirected?

In **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/** 
I have 3 files where I probably messed up by inexperience:

File 1: 000-default

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@monsiteweb.fr 
    ServerName monsiteweb.fr
    ServerAlias monsiteweb.fr *.monsiteweb.fr
    Redirect permanent   / https://www.monsiteweb.fr

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

File 2: monsiteweb.fr

```
    NameVirtualHost *:443

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@monsiteweb.fr
    ServerName monsiteweb.fr
    ServerAlias monsiteweb.fr *.monsiteweb.fr
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin hostmaster@monsiteweb.fr
    ServerName monsiteweb.fr
    ServerAlias monsiteweb.fr *.monsiteweb.fr

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.certs/geotrust_privatekey_2016.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.certs/geotrust_publickey_2016.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.certs/geotrust_intermediateca_2016.crt

   DocumentRoot /home/monsiteweb/www/


   <Directory /home/monsiteweb/www/>
   Options -Indexes
   AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>
```

File 3: default-ssl

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin hostmaster@monsiteweb.fr
   ServerName monsiteweb.fr
   ServerAlias monsiteweb.fr *.monsiteweb.fr


   DocumentRoot /home/monsiteweb/www
   <Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
   </Directory>
   <Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
   </Directory>

   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
   <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

  LogLevel warn

  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be able to acccess phpMyAdmin using http://127.0.0.1/phpMyAdmin or a local IP http://192.168.0.100/phpMyAdmin (for example).

Now if you want to access phpMyAdmin using your Public IP, you have to think about possible security issues. You can at least restrict the access to certain IPs and place additional Authorizations.

Your running VirtualHosts. It's a name-based system. If a request comes the system will look for the VirtualHost that matches the request and it will based it on ServerName and ServerAlias. If the name is not found, the system will automatically respond with the DEFAULT VIRTUAL HOST - 000-default.conf and default-ssl.conf.

With http://Your_Public_IP/phpMyAdmin, Your_Public_IP would be searched from among the named hosts and obviously it won't find it there. So it will respond with whatever is in the DEFAULT VIRTUAL HOST (which you have configured to serve https://monsiteweb.fr).

You mentioned that anyone who points to monsiteweb.fr should be redirected to https://www.monsiteweb.fr. So I assume you don't desire that people using http://Your_Public_IP would be redirected there as well.

You can configure a simple redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName *.monsiteweb.fr
  Redirect 301 / https://www.monsiteweb.fr
</VirtualHost>
```

This will redirect all the traffic except traffic for http://Your_Public_IP. If you use that to access phpMyAdmin it should already work.

Comment: thx for help. I dident knew it was possible to acess phpMyAdmin in local,  I tried with my local IP but got a 404 not found and no more success with http://127.... I then tried the simple redirect solution with http://My_Public_IP but was still redirected to https://www.monsiteweb.fr. (I modified the 000-default file ). Maybe I'm missing some other file to modufy ?